# SQL Server query assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

I have two tables that I'm trying to JOIN together. In table `TblClient1` I have a `ClientID` with a bunch of client information - such as DOB, Names, Address and so forth.

In the other table `TblClient2` I again have a `clientID` - but here is client's department - where they work (it's an `DeptID` that I'm trying to get).

The problem I'm facing is that each one of the tables has multiple instances of the same client. So in `tblClient2`, I can have up to 2 instances of the same client, and the same with `tblClient2` (here I can have even 20 instances, but with the same `DeptID` in each case).

All in all I'm trying to link `tblClient1` and `tblClient2` by `ClientID` and in my results see `ClientID` and `DeptID` (only one instance).

Any and all help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the DeptID is always the same, you can use `MAX()` or `MIN()` to return only one.

```
SELECT T1.ClientID, MAX(DeptID)
FROM TblClient T1
INNER JOIN TblClient T2 on T1.ClientID = T2.ClientID
GROUP BY T1.ClientID
```